# Freeze an android application

Tags: java, android

I want to create a timer for the screen in an application to be frozen. Let's say like two seconds. I don't want the screen to react to any on screen button clicks. Is this "frowned" upon? Or is there another way of going about this.

My application:

[image]

User click:

[image]

I want to then pause everything for two seconds (so my other buttons listeners don't go off) and then I want the listeners to go back, because I'll turn the button back from green to grey.

Comment: No one can say if it's frowned upon until you say why you want to do it.

Comment: And once we know what you are really trying to accomplish, we can perhaps recommend other solutions.

Comment: Well, long story short, the user hits a button and then I change the color of the button (to indicate right or wrong) While I'm indicating right or wrong I want to disable all of the other buttons until I change the color back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click handler you could change the color and remove the onclick listener for all buttons and start a background thread that does your timing.  When the background thread has slept for 2 minutes then you can add the onclick listeners back for all buttons.  That way you don't create a UI that is totally unresponsive, but you achieve the effect of disabling the buttons.

```
public class myListener implements OnClickListener() {
  private boolean ignoreClicks = false;

  public void setIgnoreClicks( boolean b ) { 
    this.ignoreClicks = b;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick( View v ) {
    if ( !ignoreClicks ) {
      // use v to get the button, then change the color
      ignoreClicks = true;
      // start a new AsyncTask and give it the listener and the view
      // in doInBackground sleep for 2 seconds
      // in onPostExecute change the color of the button back to normal
      //     (you have a reference to the button because you gave the view to the AsyncTask)
      //   and set ignoreClicks to false in the listener
    }
  }
}
```

Create one instance of this listener and use it for every button.

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove the onclick listener for all buttons? Because let's say I have 50 buttons, that's a lot of listeners to stop and then start back up again.

Comment: Still not enough context.  Create an array of your button objects, then iterate that array and call setOnClickListener(null);

Comment: You could have an onclick listener implementation that looks at the view that was clicked, changes the color of that view, and then while it may receive clicks it doesn't do anything with them until your timeout has occurred.  Then you could use a single instance of that listener for every button, so the first click would cause the event, all the others would go through the no-op path of the listener method until the timeout occurs and the listener is again active.

Comment: So would there be a piece of code I can write to ignore all clicks?

Comment: edited question and added pseudo code.